# Rails where condition on un-persisted association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to do

```
@destination.ratings.where(:name => 'monkey')
```

when none of the models are yet persisted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No there isn't, but you may just use normal Ruby methods like [`Array#select`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000251) to go through your unsaved models.

The `where` method and its bandmates in ActiveRecord generate SQL queries for the database, so if the model instances aren't in the database, it won't find anything.

Something like

```
@monkey = @destination.ratings.select{|rating| rating.name == 'monkey' }.first
```

could do the trick

Comment: I would recommend `.detect` It will be faster as it gets the first one that matches what's in the block without needing to go through the entire array to just get the first one in the first place.

Comment: @JordanMichaelRushing Is that new? It wasn't there back in 2011

Comment: detect has been apart of ruby since 2008: https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_8_6_287/Enumerable/detect